# How to map "Ctrl+>" combination in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to map the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>></kbd> combination to <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> (go to next vim tab).

Because `>` is a special character, `nmap <c->> gt` does not work.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: I tried to type the combination in insert mode and it does inserted some text (I tried <Ctrl> + <Tab>). How could I map it to something?

Comment: @astronaut: Ctrl-Tab is just `<C-Tab>`, and yes, this will work (at least in GVIM).

Answer (score 7):

You can map every key by its `termcap` code. And by decimal (octal, hexa) code. Please read:

```
:h :map-special-chars
```